# Authenticate on Wordpress with wget

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, windows-7, wget

I would like to login via Wget onto a Wordpress website.

I have found on StackOverflow something related to basic authentication.

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
--post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
http://server.com/auth.php
```

and tried this with a WordPress site but did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This worked for me for one of the Drupal projects I worked on sometime ago. Its answered by asciikewl on the Drupal thread https://drupal.org/node/118759

---

I've managed to get it working this way, using wget's own cookie handling:
I'm also referencing the /user page, not a login block (not enabled on my site)

```
#!/bin/sh
site=http://your site url with a slash on the end/
name=ScriptUser
pass=somethingsecure
cookies=/tmp/cron-cookies.txt
wget -O /dev/null --save-cookies /tmp/ba-cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies $cookies "${site}user"
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies $cookies --load-cookies $cookies -O /dev/null \
    --post-data="name=$name&pass=$pass&op=Log%20in&form_id=user_login" \
    "${site}user?destination=login_redirect"
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies $cookies --load-cookies $cookies "${site}login_redirect"
```

### Maybe with the wget cookie handling you can recurse the site.

Answer (score 2):

For WordPress, you're only missing a tiny bit, which is the `testcookie=1`. Also you probably need a User-Agent otherwise you may receive a "403 Forbidden" response.

So all together the script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

site="http://server.com"
login_address="$site/wp-login.php"
log="username"
pwd="password"
cookies="/tmp/cookies.txt"
agent="Mozilla/5.0"

# authenticate and save cookies
wget \
    --user-agent="$agent" \
    --save-cookies $cookies \
    --keep-session-cookies \
    --delete-after \
    --post-data="log=$log&pwd=$pwd&testcookie=1" \
    "$login_address"

# access home page with authenticated cookies
wget \
    --user-agent="$agent" \
    --load-cookies $cookies \
    "$site"
```

Pro tip:
using Chrome Developers tools, in the "Network" tab, you can "Copy as cURL", which is not too far from wget format.

[image: Copy as cURL]

Comment: This actually proved to work for me. @user3140607, can you mark this as the solution, if it works for you too?